# How to group users data on mongo db

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am trying to order the result from a monogo database, this is the equivalent in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE user1 = 'josieboy' or user2='josieboy' GROUP by user1, user2
```

This is my mongoDB query:

```
var query = Chat.aggregate(
    {
        $match:{
            $or:[
                {'user1':data}, 
                {'user2':data}
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        $group : { 
            _id: '$user1', 
            receiver : { $first: '$user1' }, 
            sender : { $first: 'user2' } 
        }
    }, 
    {
        $project : {"_id":0, "user1":1, "user2":1}
    }
);
```

The query returns more than the expected result :

**RETURNED RESULT**

id    user1         user2              Message

1     fred          josieboy           HI
2     josieboy    fred               Wts up
3     racheal       josieboy           HI

**EXPECTED RESULT**

id    user1         user2              Message

2     josieboy      fred               Wts up
3     racheal       josieboy           HIy

I would want to return a single match for Fred and Josieboy regardless of the number of rows returned and who is the user1 or user2 order by the latest id and latest message.

I would also be glad if the update query could be in mongodb ...

THanks

Comment: Can you show your MongoDB query? And why is the message with id 1 unexpected?

Comment: @Schore. This is my mongoDB query:      var query = Chat.aggregate({$match:{$or:[{'user1':data}, {'user2':data}]}},
   
   {$group : {
    _id: '$user1',
                receiver : { $first: '$user1' },
    sender : { $first: 'user2' }
    }}
   
   , {$project : {"_id":0, "user1":1, "user2":1}}
   
   );

Answer (score 0):

It's long and ugly but I think does what you want:

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $match: {
        $or: [{
            'user1': data
        }, {
            'user2': data
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        user1: 1,
        user2: 1,
        Message: 1,
        users: ["$user1", "$user2"]
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$users"
}, {
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $eq: ['$users', data]
            },
            then: '$$PRUNE',
            else: '$$KEEP'
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$users',
        __id: {
            $last: '$_id'
        },
        user1: {
            $last: '$user1'
        },
        user2: {
            $last: '$user2'
        },
        Message: {
            $last: '$Message'
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: '$__id',
        user1: 1,
        user2: 1,
        Message: 1
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your accurate answer.  You saved me the troubles